# I'm running the project to test using TestNG java in eclipse but I get an error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, tomcat8, testng-eclipse

I have applied the `jdk21` library instead of the default, and selenium server `4.15.0` and also installed tomcat `8.5` but when I run it I get an error.

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed Agent_OnLoad: instrument
```

I tried downloading `aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar` into the `aspectjweaver` folder but running it again still got the error.

Comment: have you configured your Java with your system configuration? also, you can switch back to the accepted Java version by right-clicking on the project and going to build path and edit and apply.